# Correct way to convert timezone offset in minutes to 24h format

Tags: go

I'm receiving a timezone offset in minutes ie. 240 (representing GMT-4) and need to convert it to   -0800 or -08:00. How can I do that correctly in Go lang?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do it:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "time"
)

func zone(s string, d time.Duration) *time.Location {
   f := d.Seconds()
   return time.FixedZone(s, int(f))
}

func main() {
   z := zone("GMT-4", -240 * time.Minute)
   t := time.Date(2021, 3, 30, 19, 22, 53, 0, z)
   fmt.Println(t) // 2021-03-30 19:22:53 -0400 GMT-4
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/time#FixedZone

Comment: I came to the same conclusion, I didn't like that the FixedZone had an arbitrary named associated with it but I'm actually ignoring it completely. Oh well, this was a strange edge case anyways.